# Non-HTML circle text labels on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, image, rasterization

I need to save image of Leaflet map with polygon, multi-polygons, circles and text below every circle. I have geojson file with circle and polygon coordinates (lat and lng). I managed to get image of Leaflet map with circles and polygons with Leaflet-image library (https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image), but it can't rasterize html and labels are made in html.

Is it possible to create non-html text labels below every circle which would be rasterized with Leaflet-image? Is there a way to show some text labels which can be rasterized with some other web mapping libraries, like Mapbox or OpenLayers?